# Can we ignore all parameters in URLs using a switch somewhere for their merchant account?

Tags: javascript

My client has text in their URL which are the same name as the Mention Me parameters. This means that despite them passing me locale=en_GB in the tag we ignore this and override it with the locale=uk-uk that we see in their requesting page URL.

How can I avoid this so that the correct parameters are used from the Javascript tag only and we ignore any other rogue parameters that appear in the URL?

Comment: Your question is too broad. Please edit your question and include more references to the system/framework in use as well as relevant code snippets.

Answer (score 0):

[Edit brand > advanced options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/af3X3.png)

You can select the second option in the advanced options area of the edit brand view. This will allow you to only accept parameters from a requesting URL if it has the format "mm_" first e.g. "mm_locale=."

Using this method we are able to ignore the incorrect parameters that previously were overriding the correct Javascript parameters.